# MS Word VBA - Hide ActiveX Command Button

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hej,

so I am trying to write a macro where I hide all Command Buttons and then have it printed as a pdf. Easy when using Excel-VBA, but apparently not as easy when wanting to do the same with Word. Anyone has an idea how to solve it?
`.Shapes` and `.InLineShapes`, but cannot find a `.hidden` or `.visible` command, and OLE commands aren't really there. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's wrong. My command buttons were setup incorrectly. Somehow they got formatted in a weird way, so that when I want to run a ```.select´´´command, they weren't. New set of buttons fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you are talking about `ActiveX` CommandButtons, as you say? If so, AFAIK they do not expose a `Visible` property as in Excel... Anyhow, I do not see the need of selecting, too.

Comment: You are right, BUT if you write it like this `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(5).Range.Font.Hidden = True` , then it does the same ;)

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't, if an `ActiveX` `CommandButton`... Please, try `Debug.Print TypeName(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(5).OLEFormat.Object)`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`?

Comment: It returns ´SpinButton´

Comment: So, a `SpinButton` is not a `CommandButton` as you said. Such a control can be handled only making its dimensions (`Height` and `Width) = 05, placing the object in an array, the corresponding EXISTING dimensions in another array and restore them after printing or whatever is necessary to do it when not visible...

Comment: That is because I deleted something since, so the number changed. But I got to the same cconclusion with the spin button. Also got the commandbutton to work :)

Comment: Do you want saying that you succeeded to hide an `ActiveX` `CommandButton` using `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(x).Range.Font.Hidden = True`? Where `x` is the index number of the `CommandButton` control...

Comment: yes and no. The buttons disappear, when using `.Hidden = True` BUT, when you scroll up and down, they show up again. Anyways, I decided to go for the `.Height` solution